# Работа с phpQuery возникает ошибка при запуске foreach Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, парсер, phpquery

Знания php у меня сырые, решил потренироваться с парсингом данных с сайта с помощью phpQuery остановился в самом начале и уже довольно продолжительное время перебираю варианты.

При запуске foreach возникает ошибка:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /parser.php on
>   line 13

про нее читал, но проблему решить не помогло.
подскажите что дописать нужно, что не так делаю?

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    require 'phpQuery.php';

    $url='http://ria56.ru/posts/news/';
    $file= file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);

    $rianews=$doc->find('.text_posts');//извлекаем только новостные посты

    $links = $doc->find('.text_posts .name a')->attr('href');

    foreach ($doc->find('.name a')->attr('href') as $link){
        echo $link.'<br>';
    }
```

сама библиотека подлючена, так как ссылка извлеклась с помощью

```
$links = $doc->find('.text_posts .name a')->attr('href');
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно перебирать ссылки из списка найденных, а потом брать их атрибуты. Правильный вариант будет примерно таким:

```
foreach ($doc->find('.name a') as $link){
    echo $link->attr('href') . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: пробовал.. Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::attr() in /parser.php on line 12

Comment: и странно что не распознал ведь если просто написать echo $doc->find('.name a')->attr('href') то первая ссылка выведится

Answer (score 1):

решил проблему, оказалось что `$link`являлся объектом **DOMElement**, а нам нужен **phpQueryObject** для этого нужно было сделать следующее

```
foreach ($doc->find('.name a') as $link){
    $link = pq($link);
    echo $link->attr('href') . '<br>';
}
```

после преобразований во второй строке с переменной `$link` можно работать как с объектом jquery и уже писать что то вроде: `$link->attr('href')`

Вывод: надо было подробнее читать документацию.
https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/wikis/Basics.wiki